# Fast text processing in python on dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, nltk, text-processing

I am working on an e-commerce data in python. I have loaded that data in python and converted it into a pandas data frame. Now I want to perform text processing on that data like removing unwanted characters, stopwords, stemming etc. currently the code that I have applied is working fine but it takes a lot of time. I have around 2 million rows of data to process and it takes forever to process it. I tried that code on 10,000 rows and it took around 240 seconds. I am working on this kind of project for the first time. Any help to reduce time would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import re

def textprocessing(text):
    stemmer = PorterStemmer()
    # Remove unwanted characters
    re_sp= re.sub(r'\s*(?:([^a-zA-Z0-9._\s "])|\b(?:[a-z])\b)'," ",text.lower())
    # Remove single characters
    no_char = ' '.join( [w for w in re_sp.split() if len(w)>1]).strip()
    # Removing Stopwords
    filtered_sp = [w for w in no_char.split(" ") if not w in stopwords.words('english')]
    # Perform Stemming
    stemmed_sp = [stemmer.stem(item) for item in filtered_sp]
    # Converting it to string
    stemmed_sp = ' '.join([x for x in stemmed_sp])
    return stemmed_sp
```

I am calling this method on that dataframe:

```
files['description'] = files.loc[:,'description'].apply(lambda x: textprocessing(str(x)))
```

You can take any data as per your convenience. Due to some policy, I am not able to share the data.

Comment: one quick change that may help: it looks like the stopwords is normally a list, and has 2400 entries in it. making it a set should speed up the `if not w in stopwords` considerably. try your change on a smaller extract first. also, apply seems to be slower than normal list comprehension sometimes - may be worth extracting the column, doing your code (which is actually a good bit of processing) as a list comprehension, and then reinserting...

Comment: I've experienced before that `apply` on pandas are considerably slower than applying functions in other structures like lists or dictionaries.
Is there a specific reason you want them in a `pandas.DataFrame`? Have you considered using another one?

Comment: I am loading it through database. That's why I am converting it to a DataFrame to work on it. Is there any other data storing option that I can apply and work easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try to finish it in one loop and not create stemmer/stop_word every loop

```
  STEMMER = PorterStemmer()
  STOP_WORD = stopwords.words('english')
  def textprocessing(text):

    return ''.join(STEMMER.stem(item)  for token in re.sub(r'\s*(?:([^a-zA-Z0-9._\s "])|\b(?:[a-z])\b)'," ",text.lower()).split() if token not in STOP_WORD and len(token) > 1)
```

you could also use nltk to remove unwant word

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
STEMMER = PorterStemmer()
STOP_WORD = stopwords.words('english')
TOKENIZER = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
def textprocessing(text):
    return ''.join(STEMMER.stem(item)  for token in TOKENIZER.tokenize(test.lower()) if token not in STOP_WORD and len(token) > 1)
```

Comment: Thanks..!!! It certainly improved the speed by few times with few fixes in the code.